# Does convexification preserve Lipschitz continuity?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lipschitz-functions

I am facing the following problem:

Consider a $d$-Lipschitz continuous and convex function $f$ defined on $\Delta$ that is the simplex of dimension $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Let $G$ be a finite grid of pairs point-value :
$$
G = \{(b_1, f(b_1)),...,(b_k, f(b_k)) \}
$$
where $b_i \in\Delta$ for all $i \in [1, k]$.

Now consider $\bar{f}$ the convexification of $f$ restricted to the pairs of the grid $G$. $\bar{f}$ is defined on $\Delta$  as follows:
$$
\bar{f}(b) = \min_{\lambda} \sum_{i =1}^k\lambda_if(b_i)
$$
where $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$ and $\sum_i \lambda_i b_i = b$

I would like to prove that the function $\bar{f}$ is $d$-Lipschitz continuous on the simplex (for the 1-norm: $||x||_1 = \sum_i|x_i|$)

Does anyone recommend any litterature or have any hints?

Regards

Comment: The function $\bar f$ is piecewise linear, hence it is trivially Lipschitz continuous. Or do you want to show the stronger claim that the Lipschitz constant of $\bar f$ is at most the Lipschitz constant of $f$? Well, that is not true...

Comment: Yeas I wanted to show that the Lipschitz constant was preserved... Do you recommend any litterature about convexification operators ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy counterexample:
Consider $f(x,y) = y^2$ and
restrict $f$ to the points
$$
(0,0), (1-\varepsilon, 0), (1,1), (1,-1)
$$
Then, the Lipschitz constant of the convexification is $\varepsilon^{-1}$.

Comment: The grid points are meant to belong do $\Delta$..

Comment: What do you mean by "the grid points"?